# Building server with java and spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web

So I am building some kind of home server(I am using java and Spring MVC), the sole purpose of this web app is to enable all users to listen to songs/ watch movies that are on my database. Currently everything works as expected (Only I am using this web app, on localhost), but I am concerned what will happen when there is more than one user. I am not using anything special, and this is my first project of this kind. So for each mapping, I am using only one controller, and outputting only 1 page. So my question is will this kind of web server work as expected with multiple users if it works with one.

Comment: Can't you get a couple of friends to test it and see what happens?

Comment: it's on localhost, so I can test it only from my computer.

Comment: Based on the question nobody can tell you if you are going to have problems. You have to test it in a realistic setting. You can simulate a couple of users yourself with incognito windows in chrome or firefox, but ideally you should get real users or people behaving like ones to test it. You could consider creating a load test benchmark with jmeter or some such to stress the most used parts of the app, but it sounds like at this moment you don't even know how the users will behave.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try to simulate multiple users. Is there any special method of programing I should use in order to not have problems when multiple users are on site(coz in this site users will play songs and movies, and it wont be just html file.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned in which server you are deploying your application. So, I'm assuming tomcat.

Handling multiple requests part will be handled by the server. here, Tomcat uses thread connection pool and each incoming request will be assigned to a thread from the pool and once thread finishes the job, it return to the pool. So, you don't need to do anything other than a controller and your business logic.

Comment: Thanks, I am pretty sure I use tomcat, when I start my application it says:''o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path'', i think this means I am running tomcat.